# Macports / fink / homebrew - which allows true non-root, home-directory-only installation?

Tags: homebrew, development, macports, fink

I'm looking into doing some development on my Macbook Pro running Yosemite. I've used both Macports and homebrew before, but I really don't want to install anything on my machine outside of my home directory. Ideally I would be able to have everything installed under $HOME and still be able to link libraries such as SDL, install things like pygame, etc.

I've read various other StackExchange posts about the three main tools (that I'm aware of, and which are mentioned in the title of this message) but I don't think I've seen a clear answer with regard to my question. Is there one?